# Why is ItemTouchHelper not restoring the original view when deleted then added again?

Tags: java, android

I have a Itemtouchhelper with a FirebaseRecyclerAdapter set up for my recycler view. For my recyclerview row I have 2 layouts one in the front and one in the back. When I swipe the the row the top moves and leaves the bottom view. The problem is when it deletes the the row, then I add another item, the view just shows the back of the layout and not the front on the position of the old deleted item,

I tired a solution I found online where I would remove itemTouchHelper from my recyclerview then add it again, as well as notifying my adapter of the change.

This is my code

```
ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback itemTouchHelpCallBack = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT) {
            @Override
            public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
                View foregroundView = viewHolder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.foregroundView);
                getDefaultUIUtil().onDraw(c, recyclerView, foregroundView, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {

                cartAdapter.getRef(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).removeValue();
                list.remove(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
                totalPrice.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.totalPrice, String.valueOf(TotalPriceCalc(list))));




            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution,

I was missing

```
 @Override
            public void clearView(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
                View foregroundView = viewHolder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.foregroundView);
                getDefaultUIUtil().clearView(foregroundView);
            }
```